# Failed to establish outbound s2s connection

Tags: ejabberd

I'm getting this error when trying to chat between 2 registered users

```
04:54:07.632 [warning] Failed to establish outbound s2s connection host -> user: DNS lookup failed: non-existing domain; bouncing for 74 seconds
```

this is all on my lan, because the intention is a LAN only chat, I use dnsmasq as a resolver and I don't have any issues. I made sure all certs are fine.

Answer (score 0):

> this is all on my lan, because the intention is a LAN only chat

Perfect, so let's asume you configured ejabberd like this in ejabberd.yml:

```
hosts:
  - "host"
```

> trying to chat between 2 registered users

Ok, then let's assume you registered two accounts, and you can login to them: `bob@host` and `user@host`

> Failed to establish outbound s2s connection host -> user: DNS lookup failed: non-existing domain; bouncing for 74 seconds

With that log message, it seems as if you logged in account `bob@host`, and tried to add as contact an account with JID `user`.

That is wrong, because you provided only the username part of the JID.

Solution: you must provide the bare JID, which includes username and server, for example: `user@host`. So, let me repeat: even if your ejabberd configuration has only one host, and even if you only plan to have local user chat with other local users... in the clients you must always provide the bare JID, which includes the username and the servername.

Comment: You were right, It's working now. Thanks